# Adding an extra word to a php variable?

Tags: php

Here is part of something im trying to do, Where ive got the 2nd $course_item .= i want to add a word here so its actually like:

cerealchoices or toastchoices etc etc

How can i add the word choices to the end of the $course_item variable?

This is to loop through all the text boxes.

```
$course_menuname = $row['course_menuname']; #E.G breakfast_cereal, breakfast_toast
$course_item = $row['course_jsname']; #E.G cereal, toast, jacketpotato
if(!empty($course_menuname)) {
   foreach($course_menuname as $course_item) {
    $course_item = trim($course_item);
    if(!empty($course_item)) {
      $course_item .= "$course_item;";
    }
   }
 }
```

This is what i want it to look like:

```
$course_menuname = $row['course_menuname']; #E.G breakfast_cereal, breakfast_toast
$course_item = $row['course_jsname']; #E.G cereal, toast, jacketpotato
if(!empty($_POST['breakfast_cereal'])) {
   foreach($_POST['breakfast_cereal'] as $cereal) {
    $cereal= trim($cereal);
    if(!empty($cereal)) {
      $cerealchoices .= "$cereal;";
    }
   }
 }
```

Where it says cerealchoices, in the first one the variable $course_item has the word cereal i want to add the world choices to the end of it?

Answer (score 2):

```
$course_item = "{$row['course_jsname']}choices";
```

Should do what you need. Note that the curly braces aren't actually printed, they just tell PHP to treat all of the contained text as a variable.

Comment: I didn't actually word my original question very well, Here is more of my script and what i want it too look like: http://pastebin.com/HpniXeCX, You see where it says $cerealchoices .= "$cereal;"; on line 26, How can i add the word choices to the looped one?

Comment: @Exoon It would be better for everyone if you edited your original question with the new information. Paste your code in as well!

Comment: What is the output of `$course_item` that you are expecting in the end? Currently I think it'd look something like `"cereal;toast;jacketpotato;"`, so how are you expecting it to look?

Comment: Yes that is how i want it to end up like.

Comment: If I'm reading your questions edit correctly, you want it to look like `"cereal;toast;jacketpotato;choices"`. Correct? If so you'd add another append outside of your foreach loop. `$course_item .= "choices";`

Comment: i added a more detailed explanation here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19664388/how-to-recreate-this-forloop-to-work-many-times

Answer (score 2):

This should help you with your goal :)

```
$course_item = $row['course_jsname']."choices";
```

Although Philip Pryce has a more elegant solution :)

Read more in [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i didn't actually word my original question very well though, ive added a response to Phillips answer, do you know how to do this?